# Pyinstaller generating EXE that does nothing

Tags: python, windows-10, pyinstaller

After upgrading to pyinstaller 3.6 any EXE that I generate do nothing.
I've tried a simple one (hello.py):

```
print('hello')
```

Than I've used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile hello.py
```

The result is:

```
172 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
173 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
176 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
182 INFO: wrote C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\hello.spec
186 INFO: UPX is not available.
190 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\coliveira\\OneDrive\\Coding\\Python\\email_gen',
 'C:\\Users\\coliveira\\OneDrive\\Coding\\Python\\email_gen']
190 INFO: checking Analysis
191 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
192 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
202 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
226 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
11989 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
12316 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
12321 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\coliveira\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe
13217 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\hello.py
13221 INFO: Processing module hooks...
13222 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
13459 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
13461 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
14168 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
14175 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
14184 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
14209 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
14651 INFO: Looking for eggs
14652 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\coliveira\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python38.dll
14656 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
14675 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\build\hello\warn-hello.txt
14829 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\build\hello\xref-hello.html
14863 INFO: checking PYZ
14863 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
14868 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\build\hello\PYZ-00.pyz
16723 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\build\hello\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
16756 INFO: checking PKG
16756 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
16767 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
20189 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
20199 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\coliveira\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
20200 INFO: checking EXE
20201 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
20204 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
20213 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\coliveira\OneDrive\Coding\Python\email_gen\dist\hello.exe
20374 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

My environment:

- Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916
  32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- PyInstaller version 3.6
- Windows 10 Enterprise [Version 10.0.17763.1158] 64-bits

Any ideas? Thanks. Celso

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just printing your message and closing straight away? Try adding `import time` and then after your print line, `time.sleep(3)`.

Comment: thanks wstk. I'm testing it using the command prompt... but I've tried your suggestion anyway and it doesn't work. something happened with the environment after upgrading PyInstaller. I even tried to uninstall and install the previous version of it that was working yesterday. same problem.